# withFile handle is empty

Tags: haskell, io

In my current working directory there is a file named `test.txt`, which contains `"Test\n"`.

With `System.IO.readFile`, GHCI returns the content:

```
Prelude System.IO> readFile "test.txt"
"Test\n"
```

But not so with the following, which should be equal in my opinion:

```
Prelude System.IO> withFile "test.txt" ReadMode hGetContents
""
```

Why is it not the case? How to get the whole file contents within the `withFile` `IO` action?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Lazy IO is evil.

What happens is that `hGetContents` returns an IO-lazy list of the file contents. This means that the file handle will be read only when said list is actually accessed. Then the control passes to `withFile` which closes the file handle. Finally, the result is printed, and the list is demanded: only now a read is performed on the handle. Alas, it's too late.

As an ugly, manual "flush" of this laziness, you can try e.g.

```
hGetCont handle = do
   c <- hGetContents handle
   length c `seq` return c
```

The above forces the length of the list to be computed, hence forcing the whole file to be read. Reid Barton below suggest more beautiful alternatives, which avoid the use of the horribly evil lazy IO.

Comment: Thanks, but this only answers the first question. Is there a way to flush this laziness?

Comment: @ominug, you should just not use `withFile` and `hGetContents` together. Use `readFile`, or `openFile` and `hGetContents`.

Comment: @reid-barton But what can then be used with `withFile`?

Comment: Strict IO functions like `hGetLine`.

Comment: @reid-barton Ok. But `withFile` is just `openFile` and `hClose` around a lambda. I think this really breaks the notion of reproducible/constant values. So is there a recommendation to always handle `hGetContents` with care?

Comment: Lazy IO as implemented in Haskell is evil.  There's nothing about the concept of `hGetContents` that forces it to be implemented that way.

Comment: You should not manually close a handle (including via `withFile`) that you have passed to `hGetContents` (unless you are sure you have already consumed as much of the file as you will ever need). If you consume the entire file, `hGetContents` will close the file automatically for you.